# Using History API for Ajax div load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, url

In my WP site I have post content loaded into a div with ajax on a click event.
I need it now to change the url for the current post, would prefer not using hashes. 
How would I implement this using my js?

JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#main-content').on('click', '.page a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
      });
    });
```

I have researched History API but I'm not sure how to implement it with my js.

Comment: [See here for a thorough answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26950030/1922144).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this yet myself, but this should be very simple using the pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "New Page Title", "newPath.html");
```

Here's an extended example, where you would replace the content, path, and title with the results from your WordPress query that would grab the next post.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Push State Testing</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var i = 1;
            function goToPage( pageNumber, pushState ) {
                var content  = "Hello World " + pageNumber,
                    path     = "hello_world_" + pageNumber,
                    title    = content,
                    stateObj = {"content":content}
                ;
                document.title = title;
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;
                if( pushState ) {
                    history.pushState({index:pageNumber}, title, path);
                }
                i = pageNumber;
            }
            function nextPage() {
                goToPage( i+1, true );
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                goToPage(1);
                history.replaceState({index:1}, "Hello World 1", "hello_world_1");
            }
            window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                goToPage(event.state.index, false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='content'>Push State Testing</div>
        <button type='button' onclick='nextPage()'>Next</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In answer to the question in the comments. No, you don't need to know the path of the URL until you know the content.  You replace the content and do the pushState at the exact same time:

```
$('#mainContent').html( contentFromWp );
history.pushState( state, titleFromWp, pathFromWp );
```

Okay, so to take the above and try to write it for you, which I can't test, so I can't guarantee that this will be working like my above examples...it would be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#main-content').on('click', '.page a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        title = jQuery(this).attr('title')
    ;
    jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
    document.title = title;
    history.pushState({url:url,title:title}, title, url );
  });
});

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    document.title = event.state.title;
    jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(event.state.url+ ' #main-content');
}
```

Note the need for onpopstate to make the back button work.  You will also want to call a history.replaceState when your webpage first loads like I did in my example so that when users go back to the very first page the first page they were on will reload...otherwise, the user will only be able to go back to the second page they navigated to since going back to the first won't have a stateObj.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea how instead of newPath.html it would show my next WP post name?

Comment: @MiaGilin If you're able to grab the HTML, don't you also know the URL for that post?

Comment: It's wordpress, it's all done dynamically. There are thousands of posts. I need a solution where the click will automatically grab the url from the next post and so on continuously for all posts.

Comment: @MiaGilin, based on what it sounds like you need, I've appended to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I feel like you misunderstood my question. My js is working all properly, it retrieves my correct posts and all. The only issue is that the address bar doesn't reflect the post being viewed. I just need to add to my current js the ability to reflect the post name in the url. Maybe the site link would help? http://radonicrodgers. com/recent/copperrun-brand-identity-wins-2nd-award-at-summit-creative-awards-1

Comment: @MiaGilin, WordPress must hand you two pieces of information: The new content AND the path that would bring the user to that post if they went to that post directly.  If it doesn't give you both of those pieces of information, then it's a WordPress issue.  If you have both of those pieces of information, then pushState does everything you just said.  It changes the URL in the browser and creates a new entry in the history for the previous page.

Comment: I have urls for all the posts, but there is only 1 page. All of the posts load into that 1 page. Are you telling me to physically write out all the urls for thousands of posts into that 1 page? it doesn't work that way. I need a way for the next url to be grabbed dynamically without me needing to write out each one.

Comment: @MiaGilin, No, you don't need to know the path to that file until you also know the content.  You get them both from WP and then replace the content and pushState.  I've updated with an extended example and how to do the pushState from WP.

Comment: No, your solution makes no sense. Don't understand why you are rewriting the url, it should just grab it from my existing Next button. There needs to be no writing of the url. You mentioned you're not familiar with wp, I'm sure this would work for a plain html site but not in this instance.

Comment: @MiaGilin ...You're asking why I'm changing the URL?  Your Question stated: "I need it now to change the url for the current post, would prefer not using hashes."  If that's not your question, please rewrite your question so that your question asks what you're really asking.  I've been programming JavaScript for 15 years, doing AJAX for at least 5.  This WILL work for an AJAX loaded page...in fact, that's what pushState was written for...there is no point to pushState without an AJAX driven site.

Comment: If you would've look at the link I posted previously you would understand what I mean. Instead of you writing out "hello world" for each next post, are you able to make it so that the Permalink for the loaded past is fetched? So no creating of urls, but simply the js just grabbing the existing url for each post. Is this a bit clearer?

Comment: @MiaGilin, I did look at your code, and I understand it completely. I gave you examples that can be integrated easily if you understand the concepts behind them. But to try to be done with the conversation, I've integrated my example with the parts of your code that are already written. You will, however, still have to write the window.onload piece as per my example code that puts the stateObject into the history so that when your users navigate back to the first page it will reload.

Comment: Thank you Kevin :) you got it to work. I wish you all the best!

Comment: +1 for hanging in there Kevin (and for answering a question I had that related to pushing state into history).